# List not working upon GetFiles method

Tags: c#, wpf, list, .net, getfiles

Trying to figure out why this isn't working, the list is to retrieve photos using the combobox item (which lists local HDDs root address as items) when selected that item it is converted into a string and supposed to be used as a path for the `GetFiles` Method but screws up on the (string path = ) line when running, I get "object reference not set to instance of an object" much appreciated If someone could tell me what is going wrong

```
public List<Photos> LoadImages ///List Retrieves and Loads Photos
    {

        get
        {
            List<Photos> Image = new List<Photos>();
            string path = HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); //ComboBox SelectedItem Converted To String As Path
            foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*jpg")) 
            {
                try
                {
                    Image.Add( //Add To List
                        new Photos(
                            new BitmapImage(
                                new Uri(filename)),
                                System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
                }
                catch { } //Skips Any Image That Isn't Image/Cant Be Loaded
            }
            return Image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This most likely means that either `HDDSelectionBox` or `HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem` is null. Have you checked for that?

Comment: mm I read into that but because I'm learning as I'm going this is new to me, my aim is to load images only when the combobox isnt null i.e only after user has selected a item from the combobox, i've a feeling its making a list right as the program loads which then of course would be null to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You should put `.` before the file extension in the line:

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg")
```

You also need to check if `HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem` is not null:

```
public List<Photos> LoadImages ///List Retrieves and Loads Photos
{
    get
    {
        List<Photos> images = new List<Photos>();
        if (HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            string path = HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); //ComboBox SelectedItem Converted To String As Path
            foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg"))
            {
                try
                {
                    images.Add( //Add To List
                        new Photos(
                            new BitmapImage(
                                new Uri(filename)),
                                System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
                }
                catch { } //Skips Any Image That Isn't Image/Cant Be Loaded
            }
        }
        return images;
    }
}
```

Also, this is probably better suited to a method rather than a property as it does quite a lot of processing...

Comment: awesome I just wandering also where my new Lists<Photos> line would go? apreciate the help so far, I had thought a while back of checking for null but it is currently expecting a get or set accessor with the addition of the if statement

Comment: That line can be before checking fur null. If HDDSelectionBox.SelectedItem is null, it will return an empty list.

Comment: so far ive public List<Photos>Load Images{ then new list<Photos>(); then the if, but it is underlining me on the new List line

Comment: thanks for that, the code runs without error but listbox shows nothing when I select a item from the combobox, It may just be my binding but I have gone through and checked

Comment: Does it return a list of `Photos` when you step through the code?

Comment: not that I can see, I'm not sure if its doing anything because I get no errors

Comment: it may be that I need to somehow move this into a event under combobox selectionchanged, because the listbox is only supposed to be filled after a drive has been selected, do correct me if I'm wrong but the list may just be sitting doing nothing seeming as its not under a event

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible